# Status of file that is deleted while another process writes to it

Tags: windows, file-management, logging, windows-server-2003, wamp

I have a WAMP that writes (very often) the logs in a file.

If I delete that file (using <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Delete</kbd>) it disappears for a moment, then it appears back (having the same size, not 0).

- When I try to open it with **Notepad** it says:

  > Access denied
- When I try to open it with **Notepad++** it says:

  > *file* doesn't exist. Create it?

  - If I select "Yes" it shows:

    > Cannot create the file "*file*".
- When I run from **cmd**:

  ```
  type file
  ```

  it shows:

  > Access is denied.
- When I run from cmd:

  ```
  dir /Q
  ```

  it shows `...` for that file, while for a normal file it shows `BUILTIN\Administrators` (where `/Q` means `Display the owner of the file.`).
- When I restart the server, the file is deleted.

**Questions:**

1. What is the status of this file? (it has to have a special status if trying to access it has a different behavior)
2. How can I change this status to a consistent state? (to be readable)
3. How does **delete** work in this case? Is it placed into a queue and executed only after the file is "released"?

Comment: Hint: This might depend on the file system and/or Windows version you use.

Comment: Theres an open handle on the file which locks it, thats how the OS/FS prevents multiple processes writing to the same file at the same time. When WAMP shuts down gracefully it should release all its handles. Manually killing its handle can be done but may cause undesired behavior or a crash.